# iOS Launch Storyboard: How can I change a Tab Bar's tint color?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

### What I'm doing:

Using a 'launch storyboard'. It's quite simple, and contains a default UITabBarController. I've set the tab bar's 'tintColor' to red in the launch storyboard, as well as in my app. I'm using Xcode 7, iOS 9.

### What doesn't work:

The launch screen loads the tab bar using the default blue iOS tint color...! Then after loading, the tint color switches to red when the launch screen storyboard is replaced.

---

**How on earth are you meant to set a tab bar's tint color in a storyboard?**

Demo Project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73998115878034693063

Comment: Quick note: I've tried setting the 'global tint' in the launch screen storyboard to red too. No luck.

Comment: I'm not sure this is supported by Launch Storyboards...

Comment: @JAL really? Wow, seems like quite a bit of an oversight if that's the case

Comment: Although you may be able to add UI elements to a launch storyboard, the only element I've found that you can change the color of is a `UIView`'s background color.  Before this, I've never tried to put anything that wasn't a `UIView` or `UIImageView` on a Launch Storyboard.  You could create an image of your tab bar with the color you want and use that as an alternative.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I can reproduce your issue.  I am able to set the colors of a `UITabBar` in a Launch Storyboard (I tried the tint and background color) and see them on launch.  Would it be possible to show a screenshot of the behavior you're experiencing?

Comment: @JAL see demo project now attached. I think I got a little further - it seems nothing I can do sets the actual tint colour from inside even the main storyboard. Setting via code, or 'user defined runtime attributes' seems to be the only solution - unfortunately launch screen storyboards do not support runtime attributes. Am I crazy, or is the fact that setting tint color from within interface builder simply doesn't work quite an oversight?

Comment: Oh wow, you set up a whole storyboard with multiple segues to view controllers as your launch screen storyboard.  I'm not sure Launch Storyboards support that.  Looking at your sample project now and will try to find an answer for you

Comment: @JAL thanks, appreciate it. It seems to support it... but maybe tinting isn't supported. Weird that tinting isn't even supported outside of a launch screen storyboard in interface builder though.

Comment: I've added a bounty to your question.  My research has pretty much turned up dry, and I don't buy that this "isn't possible."  Hope we get some good answers!

Comment: @JAL great, thanks!!

Comment: @JAL just noticed that Apple apps don't even display Tab Bar sections/images on their launch storyboards. Also noticed a popular app that shows tab bar sections but doesn't highlight anything on launch... (unsure how they do that though). I guess it's quite possible that it can't be done (or isn't meant to be)

Comment: I know how to in highlight the tabs: just have a tab bar with no connected view controllers in your launch storyboard

Comment: @JAL sure, although unless I'm mistaken you can't display any icons in the tab bar without connecting view controllers? I may be missing something

Comment: Sure you can!  I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: @JAL ha! Can't believe I didn't think of just adding a tab bar to a view controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to go is to confuse Xcode. Xcode should not know that the launch storyboard that is used is actually a `launch` storyboard. This way you would be able to set some custom `User Defined Runtime Attributes`. However, you still would NOT be able to run some custom code...

So... To do this, follow these steps:

1. Create a new Xcode project
2. Copy your `Main.storyboard` into desktop and rename it to `CustomLaunchScreen.storyboard`.
3. Add this `CustomLaunchScreen.storyboard` to the project.
4. Open your `Info.plist file` and change key `Launch screen interface file base name` value from `LaunchScreen` to `CustomLaunchScreen`.
5. Open your `CustomLaunchScreen.storyboard`. Delete the default `UIViewController` and set the `UITabBarController` as your `initial view controller`.
6. Open the `tabBar` property of your `UITabBarController` and navigate to `User Defined Runtime Attributes`
7. Add the `tintColor` property, set `type` as `Color` and set some custom value.

You can also watch a full video tutorial [Here](https://youtu.be/Zv_xi5ECG3I)

Comment: `The right way to go is to confuse Xcode`  Can't say I agree with this implementation, and I'm sure this will break with different versions of Xcode, but it does solve the issue...  Thanks, quite a hack you've found here.

Comment: Quite a lot of things break with different versions of Xcode and iOS, but I see what you mean. I wouldn't go with some hacky solutions, if Apple were good at the first place. However, as you can see, they do not always do their best -- IDE lacks quite a lot of functionality. But thanks for criticism anyways.

Comment: Have my upvote, you answered the question better than I could.  I'll wait around for a few more days but I expect to award the bounty to you if the OP is happy with this solution.  Thanks for your research!

Comment: That was quite fun, so thanks to you and @Jordan for the question

Comment: @OlDor nice hacking! I'll wait a few more days to make sure no one knows a safer way, but you deserve my up vote at the very least. I probably wouldn't use this in practice, from experience hacks like this have a knack of breaking... for now, will stick with no highlight. You've certainly answered the question - thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm going to award you the bounty, thanks again for your answer!  It's on @Jordan to accept now.

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks to @OIDor for his solution, it is a great hack.

To be clear however, you don't need to do all that. All you have to do is:

1. Edit the source of your Launch Screen storyboard and change
   `launchScreen="YES"` to `launchScreen="NO"`, this enables you to do the
   next part...
2. Add the user-defined attribute `tintColor` on the Tab Bar
   in the storyboard. This is not permitted by Xcode without the first
   step

Hey presto it's all working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out.

There are quite a few blog posts online about how Launch Storyboards work, but not a lot from Apple.  I found from [this blog post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/) which discussed that the launch screen images are captured at runtime from the launch storyboard.  Digging into my simulator directory revealed that they were in fact there:

[image: launch1]

I'm not sure why, but the call to set the `UITabBar`'s `tintColor` does not fire in time when the launch storyboard has loaded, but setting colors for other values such as the `barTintColor` property works:

[image: launch2]

All I can say is this: setting the `tintColor` on a `UITabBar` on a view controller in a launch storyboard is not supported.  There is something going on behind-the-scenes when the launch storyboard is loaded preventing this from working.

**TL;DR: you can't do this with a Launch Storyboard.**  For a workaround that tricks Xcode into treating your launch storyboard as a regular storyboard, see  [OlDor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878078/2415822).

As an alternative, you could take a screenshot of your app with the tab bar loaded properly, tweak it, and use that in a `UIImageView` on your launch view controller.

If you want to add just the tab bar without any currently selected tabs, add a `UITabBar` to your launch `UIViewController` and style the `UITabBarItem`s to your liking:

[image: tab]

This `UITabBar` has two `UITabBarItems` which can be styled without adding outlets to their view controllers.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, that wouldn't scale for different devices/orientations very well. Appreciate the help, I'll give it a few days to see if anyone has a workaround then mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Jordan no worries, great question!