# UISplitViewController AllVisible in LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

In my iPad app, the first screen is an `UISplitViewController` with `preferredDisplayMode` property set to `.AllVisible` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Is there a way to set the same property also for the launch screen storyboard?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I found a way to set `User Defined Runtime Attributes` in launch screen ([in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878078/4274793)).
So, i made an `UISplitViewController` extension with a custom property:

```
extension UISplitViewController{
    private struct CustomProperties{
        static var preferredDisplayModeFromString: String = "Automatic"
    }

    var preferredDisplayModeFromString:String {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &CustomProperties.preferredDisplayModeFromString) as! String
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &CustomProperties.preferredDisplayModeFromString, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            switch newValue {
            case "AllVisible":
                self.preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible
            case "PrimaryHidden":
                self.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryHidden
            case "PrimaryOverlay":
                self.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryOverlay
            default:
                self.preferredDisplayMode = .Automatic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can set `preferredDisplayModeFromString` from IB but this works only in the main storyboard (other attributes works also in launch screen storyboard, e.g. the tab bar tint color).

Comment: Did you found solution for this problem? As I have same problem.